# Find the general solution to the equation $y'+y=x(y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to reduce the equation $y'+y=x(y')^2$ to some standard type if possible?

Comment: See d'Alembert's equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the general solution to that differential equation, you have to use d'Alembert's Equation. Simply, rearrange the equation as:

y = xy'<sup>2</sup> - y'

See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsEquation.html